# sql group by date without time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql, and I would like to create a query that will count all my article id's for each day. but the problem the date column is also containing time.. so how I can make the query to group by just by date without time?

for example:

```
id|article_id|date (timestamp)

1|22|2014-01-10 13:30:10 
1|23|2014-02-10 12:30:10
```

Thanks
Shai

Comment: `group by date(date)`

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
select count(article_id) from YourTable group by date(date)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
select date(date), count(article_id) from YourTable group by date(date);
```

Answer (score 5):

I am too late in the race. Hope it may help some one in future.

There are 2 solution's for this

1. You can take DATE as filter option on your date timestamp in GROUP BY  as follows

   `SELECT COUNT(id) as article_count, DATE(date) GROUP BY DATE(date);`
2. You can take the alias of the SELECT column with is filtered by DATE() in GROUP BY

   `SELECT COUNT(id) as article_count, DATE(date) published_date GROUP BY published_date;`

Hope it helped. Happy Coding!

.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am the one in the future who this helped perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dayCount = 0;
$previousDay = "";     

 $query = $database->prepare('
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS date FROM my_table ORDER BY date');
 $query->execute();
 while ($output = $query->fetch()) { 

  $day = $output['date'];

  if($previousDay != $day)
   { $dayCount ++; }
  else { 
     echo $dayCount; 
     $dayCount = 0;
  }

 $previousDay = $day;

 }
```

Can can find DATE_FORMAT output here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: *I would like to create a query that will count all my article id's for each day*

Answer (score 0):

To group by date without time => use the following

NOTE: myDateTime is in date time format

GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
SELECT
COUNT(id),to_char(to_date('2014-01-10 13:30:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd') AS date_part
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY to_char(to_date('2014-01-10 13:30:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: replace date with your column name