# How to group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

Below I cannot do **Group by Date** the following figures.

I have tried to put **Group By** in different lines, but not working.

```
SELECT SUM(a.NetAmount) AS TotalDonation
FROM (
 SELECT
  (
   CASE WHEN bt.BalanceTransactionCurrencyID = 17
    THEN bt.BalanceTransactionNet
   ELSE
    bt.BalanceTransactionNet * (SELECT TOP 1 ExrateValue FROM Exrate WHERE ExrateDate < bt.BalanceTransactionCreated AND bt.BalanceTransactionCurrencyID = CurrencyID ORDER BY ExrateDate Desc)
   END
  ) AS NetAmount

 FROM Charge as ch

 JOIN BalanceTransaction as bt ON (ch.BalanceTransactionID = bt.BalanceTransactionID)

 WHERE ch.ChargeCreatedDate BETWEEN '3-1-2019' AND '3-31-2019'

) AS a
```

I wanted to see:

```
Days              Total Amount
March 1           xxxx
March 2           xxxx
March 3           xxx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql group by date without time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096840/sql-group-by-date-without-time)

Comment: That looks more like MS SQL Server code, right?

Comment: It'll be helpful for viewers if you say what your query is producing, or, if there's an error, stating that error :-)

Comment: What database are you really using?

Comment: I am getting the following error. The multi-part identifier "Charge.ChargeCreatedDate" could not be bound.

Comment: Tag properly!!  Since when MySQL has `TOP 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will hopefully display what you are looking for

```
SELECT a.Days AS Days, SUM(cast(a.NetAmount as decimal(16,9))) AS TotalDonation
FROM (
 SELECT
  (
   CASE WHEN bt.BalanceTransactionCurrencyID = 17
    THEN bt.BalanceTransactionNet
   ELSE
    bt.BalanceTransactionNet * (SELECT TOP 1 ExrateValue FROM Exrate WHERE ExrateDate < bt.BalanceTransactionCreated AND bt.BalanceTransactionCurrencyID = CurrencyID ORDER BY ExrateDate Desc)
   END
  ) AS NetAmount,
 ch.ChargeCreatedDate as Days

 FROM Charge as ch

 JOIN BalanceTransaction as bt ON (ch.BalanceTransactionID = bt.BalanceTransactionID)

 WHERE ch.ChargeCreatedDate BETWEEN '3-1-2019' AND '3-31-2019'

) AS a GROUP BY a.Days
```

This should be sufficient. You need to `SELECT` the desired value in the query in order to get it to show up. Also when using the `SUM()` function you need to specify what the group value will be.

Comment: This is just showing Transaction day and amount, not summing up the total amount in one day...

Comment: It is looking like this:

Days                          Total Donation
2019-03-01                4.58
2019-03-01                7.59
2019-03-01                5.58

Comment: Can you try the edited code? In case the Amount is NVARCHAR, this will try to cast it as decimal.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not use `TOP`.  Use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT ChargeCreatedDate, SUM(netamount)
FROM (SELECT ch.ChargeCreatedDate,
             (CASE WHEN bt.BalanceTransactionCurrencyID = 17
                   THEN bt.BalanceTransactionNet
                   ELSE bt.BalanceTransactionNet * (SELECT e.ExrateValue
                                                    FROM Exrate e
                                                    WHERE e.ExrateDate < bt.BalanceTransactionCreated AND
                                                          e.CurrencyID = bt.BalanceTransactionCurrencyID 
                                                    ORDER BY ExrateDate Desc
                                                    LIMIT 1
                                                   )
              END) AS NetAmount
      FROM Charge ch JOIN
           BalanceTransaction bt
           ON ch.BalanceTransactionID = bt.BalanceTransactionID
      WHERE ch.ChargeCreatedDate BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
     ) chtbt
GROUP BY ChargeCreatedDate;
```

If you happen to be using SQL Server, you can replace the `LIMIT 1` with `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.

Comment: This is just showing Transaction day and amount, not summing up the total amount in one day

Comment: @AbbosCoder . . . I'm confused.  There is a `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`, so it should be doing a sum.  Does the "date" column have a time component by any chance?